# Kubernetes cluster appears to have been deleted after upgrading from trial version

Tags: google-cloud-platform

After my trial version credits got depleted on GCP, I upgraded my account. However my Kubernetes cluster and all its deployments appear to have been deleted. It now appears almost like I am activating Kubernetes Engine for the very first time. What can I do to restore my Kubernetes cluster?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqDSJ.png)